# Show that for the two sided left shift operator in $\ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has $\{|\lambda | =1\} $ in its spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $S:\ell_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to \ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$ be the left shift operator $S(\ldots, x_{-2}, x_{-1}, x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (\ldots, x_{-1}, x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3 \ldots)$

I want to show that $\{|\lambda | =1\} \subset \sigma(S)$

The hint that was given is to show that if $ |\lambda | =1$, then it's an almost eigenvalue of $S$.
Namely, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $x \in \ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $||x||=1$ and $||Sx - \lambda x|| \le \epsilon$

If could find such $x$ for a given $\epsilon$, then I can easily show that $ (S - \lambda I) x$ is not invertible.

However, I am struggling to find such an $x$.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try with a normalized version of the sequence $(\ldots,0,\lambda^{-N},\lambda^{-N+1},\ldots,\lambda^0,\ldots,\lambda^{N-1},\lambda^N,0,\ldots)$, where $\lambda^0$ is at the zero-th position.

Comment: Could you elaborate how this seqeunce satisfies the condition?

Comment: No. I gave you something to work with. Maybe it wasn't a good hint, I haven't tried. Have you?

Comment: I tried but this doesn't seem to work or maybe I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion by amsmath is the canonical one. We have
$$
\sum_{k=-N}^N|\lambda^k|^2=2N+1. 
$$
So we can define
$$
x=\frac1{2N+1}\sum_{k=-N}^N\lambda^ke_k,
$$
with $N$ to be chosen later. So $\|x\|=1$ and
\begin{align}
Sx-\lambda x&=\frac1{2N+1}\Big(\sum_{k=-N}^N\lambda^ke_{k-1}-\sum_{k=-N}^N\lambda^{k+1}e_k\Big)
=\frac1{2N+1}\Big(\sum_{k=-N-1}^{N-1}\lambda^{k+1}e_{k}-\sum_{k=-N}^N\lambda^{k+1}e_k\Big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{2N+1}\Big(\lambda^{-N}e_{-N-1}-\lambda^{N+1}e_N\Big).
\end{align}
Then
$$
\|Sx-\lambda\|=\frac{\sqrt2}{2N+1}.
$$
Now can choose $N$ such that $2N+1>\sqrt2/\varepsilon$.